# Having a full name of country with localized_country_select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Formtastic with localized_country_select gem and trying to display the list of countries:

```
<%= semantic_form_for '', url: 'myUrl', method: 'POST' do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= = f.input :country, as: :country, iso_codes: false %>
    <% end %>
```

The countries use the name as the label & key as value. But I would like to have full name instead of code of country in my option's values. I've set iso_codes attribute to false but still not working. Can you tell me if there is any way to do it please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Still not working.

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your support but that still not working. Can you check the updated code please ?

Comment: Great. This is the updated code :  <%= f.input :country, as: :select, collection: I18n.translate(:countries).map {|key, value| value} %>. That works very well for me. Thanks Andrey.